# Center multiple <div>'s over image without extra <div>s in CSS

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

Imagine you have the following construction:

```
   <div>
       <img ...>
       <h3> Some h3 text </h3>
       <h2> Some h2 text </h2>
   </div>
```

Is it possible to center `<h3>` and `<h2>` over `<img>` without creating a new `<div>`? (`<h3>` and `<h2>` should not overlap). So I need basically a pure CSS solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use a img::before and img::after and remove both h3 and h2. You would just need to do a little css magic and set the Z-Index, but you can do it.

In this case you only have the img tag.

Comment: @DrBrad Thanks for your answer! But I don't have access to the HTML code, and the content of `h2` and `h3` will be changed dynamically by the user :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally possible. It's all about positioning.

```css
div {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px; /* height and width added to not just the size of the text */
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* if you want the image to be centered and cover the whole div */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
h2, h3 {
  position: relative; /* needed to render above something position absolute */
  z-index: 1; /* place above position absolute */
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/davidleininger/pen/d78407aa5e8a24612b4001e8556fa0f0

After that, it's really just about making sure you can read the text.

Another option would be to give the div a background image and center the text over that using flexbox (like above).